# prove that $P_{N}$ is a projection is to say $P_{N}^2=P_{N}$

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory

Let $\{u_1,u_2,...\}$ an orthonormal system in a space with internal product $E$, $\bigcup_{N}$ is the space generated by $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_N\}$ and the projection operator $P_{n}f$ is defined as
$$P_{N}f= \sum_{k=1} ^{N} \langle f, u_{k} \rangle u_k  $$
prove that $P_{N}$ is a projection is to say $P_{N}^2=P_{N}$

we know that $P_{N}^2f= \left(\sum_{k=1} ^{N} \langle f, u_{k} \rangle u_k\right)^2$

but I don't see an easy way to eliminate this square and reach equality, can you give me a suggestion to illuminate the way?

Comment: $u_k$ are vectors, so what does it mean $u_k^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $P_n^2f$ is wrong (and have no sens, because the operation $u_ku_j$ is not well defined).
\begin{align*}
P_n^2f&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left<P_nf,u_k\right>u_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left<f,u_j\right>\underbrace{\left<u_j,u_k\right>}_{=\delta _{kj}}u_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left<f,u_k\right>u_k\\
&=P_nf,
\end{align*}

where $\delta _{kj}=1$ if $j=k$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: you're right! with this test I have the suspicion that $P_ {N}$ is self-adjoint, this is $\langle P_nf, w \rangle=\langle f, P_{N}w\rangle$ can you verify this identity please?

Comment: Even if you write $u^2$ for $\left<u,u\right>$, $P_n^2f$ is a vector whereas $(\sum_{k}\left<f,u_k\right>u_k)^2$ is a scalar. So obviously, the equality won't hold. For your identity I let you check if it holds or not. The calculation is straightforward. @TheMartian

Comment: What property do you use to make the calculation  straightforward.?

Comment: just write $f=\sum_{i}\alpha _iu_i$, $w=\sum_{i}\beta _iu_i$, and compute $\left<P_nf,w\right>$ and $\left<f,P_nw\right>$... there is no trap, just calculation...@TheMartian

Comment: I am trying to find a counterexample because I have not been able to set equality @Surb

Comment: @TheMartian: Take $P$ the orthogonal projection on $Span\{(1,0)\}$. Take $u=(1,1)$ and $v=(1,0)$. Then  $\left<Pu,v\right>>0$ whereas $\left<u,Pv\right>=\left<u,0\right>=0$.